# Wordpress - Category list related to post

Tags: wordpress, categories

In wordpress website, I need to list all category related to the current page in sidebar. Is there any function to do this? or i need to change coding as per my need? If i want to change coding, where to change?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

How are you 'relating' these categories, through category labels or post tags? The [Category Posts Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-posts/) might be of some use, but this will only display posts made in a specified category and that doesn't sound like what you're going for.